# Navigation missing for guest users Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

There should be a navigation menu in the left column which shows up fine when I'm logged in

http://tulesblog.com/andys/

it's nothing to do with permissions, I have checked that, I have also cleared the cache a few times to no avail

Comment: Is it 'Main Menu' containing: Home, Current Issue, Submissions, etc?  I can see that fine as anonymous

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. it was silly really. as an anonymous user the login text boxes were obviously there and because of the fixed positioning the main menu was pushed out of view at the bottom of the screen. I removed the login block since it is only for admin and use the url instead and now the page looks the same to guests as it does to me. thanks for ur help